# angular not update file from app services

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know why angular does not update the file in the browser? I try to use the incognito also same. the file recently I update not reflect on the browser. ng-repeat.

the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="cgpaCalculator">
    <div class="card" ng-controller="cgpaCtrl">
    [...]
<div class="row" ng-repeat="number in data.rows track by $index">
        <div class="col-lg-5 mb-2">
           <div class="form-label-group">
               <input type="text" name="course_name" id="course_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Name [Optional]">
               <label for="course_name">Course Name [Optional]</label>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
            <div class="form-label-group">
                <select class="form-control custom-select" ng-model="data.rows[$index].grade" ng-options="grade for grade in grades track by grade">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Grade</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Controller:

[image]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you explain in more specific detail what you mean by *"update the file"*?. That is a very vague problem statement. Take a few minutes to read through [ask] then [edit] question and explain what you expect and how current behavior differs from expectations and any potential errors

Comment: Also show what `cpgaFactory.getGrades()` does as per [mre]